# PhoneGap 2.2.0 Android SplashScreen - Throwing error 'splash cannot be resolved or is not a field'

Tags: java, android, cordova, splash-screen

I am new to Java and Android development. I want to show a splashscreen in my PhoneGap 2.2.0 Android App, but when I add

```
 super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
```

to my main class (extending DroidGap)
Eclipse is throwing the error 'splash cannot be resolved or is not a field'.

Comment: thank you both! I found out by myself. But I give this to gerg84 because Tom has more points... ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`R` is a class created by the Android SDK when your application is compiled using the resources in the `res` folder. Ensure the splash image file exists in `/res/drawable/splash.png` (or required equivalent folders).

NB: The image name must be all in lower case.

Answer (score 1):

R.drawable.splash refers to a file named splash.png in res/drawable (or the resolution specific drawable folders)

Create that file and it will compile correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Phonegap version 3 and still had the same problem.

Following on from greg84 I feel its very important to note that it is literally looking for a file called `splash.png` or whatever is defined at:

```
R.drawable.splash
```

So if this was

```
R.drawable.jamie
```

you'd need to include at `*\app\platforms\android\res\drawable\jamie.png`

Hopefully this clears up the same 1 and a half hour confusion I just had.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the package of class 'R' in the code below.

```
super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
```

When you ctrl+space on the R, it shows import android.R but you have to import the same package in which you MainActivity.java(assume) is placed.Also defaultly there is no splash variable,you can create a new one and also you can use the pre-defined variable named 'ic_launcher'.Then you line of code will be ->

```
super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

Hope the problem will be solved..Cheers